# Android - Setting and Getting String Arrays in a Class

Tags: android, arrays, string

I have a class that goes like this:

```
public class Personel {

  private 
    String Name = null;
    String pathOne[] = new String[3];
    String pathTwo[] = new String[3];

  public void setName(String name){
    Name = name;
  }

  public void setPathOne(String Path[]){
    pathOne[0] = Path[0];
    pathOne[1] = Path[1];
    pathOne[2] = Path[2];
  }

  public void setPathTwo(String Path[]){
    pathTwo[0] = Path[0];
    pathTwo[1] = Path[1];
    pathTwo[2] = Path[2];
  }

  public String getName(){
    return Name;
  }

  public String getPathOne(){
    return pathOne[];
  }

  public String getPathTwo(){
    return pathTwo[];
  }
}
```

I have two String arrays, `pathOne[]` and `pathTwo[]` with three elements each. I'm having doubts if I initialized it properly.

Also, I am given an error at my `getPathOne()` and `getPathTwo()` methods.

Should I initialize the strings as:

```
private 
    String Name = null;
    String[] pathOne = new String[3];
    String[] pathTwo = new String[3];
```

and have my getPath methods as:

```
public String[] getPathOne(){
    return pathOne;
}

public String[] getPathTwo(){
    return pathTwo;
}
```

Sorry I just realized the alternative as I was typing in this question. I've yet to try it. Any help is still welcome.

Comment: Wait I'm still coding the buttons and stuff to try out the code.

Answer (score 0):

`return pathTwo[];` It is not the correct syntax.

`public String[] getPathOne(){...}` This is the right way to get `pathOne` array and what you can do alternatively `getPathOne(index)` which makes get value by index.

```
public String getPathOne(int index){
    if(pathOne.length<index)
       return pathOne[index];
    return null;
}

public String[] getPathTwo(int index){
    if(pathTwo.index<index)
       return pathTwo[index];
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Just u want store all the data to array.
2. After that u use below code.

   public class Personel {`public Array getPathOne(){
   return pathOne[];
   }

   public Array getPathTwo(){
   return pathTwo[];
   }

   }

Answer (score 0):

I think figured it out.

The private variables should be:

```
private 
    String Name = null;
    String pathOne[] = new String[3];
    String pathTwo[] = new String[3];
```

Setting the path variables are still the same. I'd really appreciate it if someone can do a short hand version of what I did above. I've yet to try `pathOne = Path;`

The return methods should be as follows

```
public String[] getPathOne(){
    return pathOne;
}

public String[] getPathTwo(){
    return pathTwo;
}
```

It works since I managed to get positive results when I tried:

```
        Personel Joe = new Personel();
        Joe.setName("Joe");
        String PathOne[] = {"X", "Y", "Z1"};

        Joe.setPathOne(PathOne);

        String pathOne[] = Joe.getPathOne();
        String name = Joe.getName();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < pathOne.length ; i ++){
            System.out.println("Personel " + name +  " Letter at index " + i + " is " + pathOne[i] + ".");
        }
```